# Tomcat welcome page not shown even though REST endpoint is working

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea, tomcat9

I followed this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ThBw3WBTw9Q and seem to access the endpoint `http://localhost:8080/HelloWebApp_war_exploded/api/hello-world` OK.

However `http://localhost:8080` gives below

```
HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
Type Status Report

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Apache Tomcat/10.0.23
```

What is the problem?

Comment: It looks like HelloWebApp_war_exploded is configured as application context in your case. Please try `http://localhost:8080/HelloWebApp_war_exploded` instead `http://localhost:8080`

Comment: @EgorKlepikov : Same error ``The requested resource [/HelloWebApp_war_exploded/] is not available``